# Getting a Method in the Main C#

Tags: c#

```
     static void bubble(int [] mas)
    {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.Length - 1; j++)
                if (mas[j] > mas[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = mas[j + 1];
                    mas[j + 1] = mas[j];
                    mas[j] = temp;
                }

        }
        foreach (var element in mas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted elements are: {0}", element);

        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] mas = new int[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the elements of the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        bubble();
    }
```

I need to be using methods to solve some tasks for Uni project and the problem I am having is that I want to create an array in the Main, use it in different methods and call the results of those methods back to the Main. When I do that and try and call the "bubble" back in to the Main it is telling me that there is no argument given that corresponds to the formal given parameter. Is there an easy way to fix that so I can fix that and proceed in creating the other methods analogically. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: in this case implement bubble is part of a task you were given, but in general, avoid to implement sorting algorithm an use what .Net already implemented. In this case, something such `List<int> mylist = new List<int>(mas); mylist.Sort();`

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error is because the function `bubble` requires an `int[]` as a parameter.

Currently you have `bubble()` which in its current state is "parameterless"

Replace it with `bubble(mas);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter in your call to bubble in main:

```
bubble(mas);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this :

```
static int[] bubble(int [] mas)
    {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.Length - 1; j++)
                if (mas[j] > mas[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = mas[j + 1];
                    mas[j + 1] = mas[j];
                    mas[j] = temp;
                }

        }
        foreach (var element in mas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted elements are: {0}", element);

        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] mas = new int[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the elements of the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        bubble(mas);
    }
```